# unable to create .csv file from Download helper code igniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I am trying to export a list page to csv file using the code below.

```
 public function export()
{
    $customers = \CI::Customers()->get_customer_export();

    \CI::load()->helper('download_helper');
    force_download('customers.csv', ($customers));
}
```

It generates and error that second parameter should be a string not any array.Also if i try to json_encode the $customers variable,it creates a file but outputs json code in the csv file.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you have to form multidimensional array. `force_download` only use for download file. In CSV you have two string with comma separated with new line.

Comment: here is my array   

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [firstname] => samar [lastname] => tanvir [email] => samartanvir09@gmail.com [email_subscribe] => 1 [phone] => root [company] => test [password] => 7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b [active] => 1 [group_id] => 1 [confirmed] => 1 [is_guest] => 0 [store_id] => 0 ) )

Comment: I answers it. You can this function as a helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this function: first of all you have put this code in helper:

```
function array_to_csv($array, $download = "")
{   
    if ($download != "")
    {    
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $download . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    }        

    ob_start();
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
    $n = 0;        
    foreach ($array as $line)
    {
        $n++;
        if ( ! fputcsv($f, $line))
        {
            show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
        }
    }
    fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
    $str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    if ($download == "")
    {
        return $str;    
    }
    else
    {    
        print "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
        print $str;
    }        
}
```

Array formation should be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => Test 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => Test 1.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [2] => Test 1.2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a 'CI database utility class' for simplicity as follows:

```
$this->load->dbutil(); 
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable"); 
echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);
```

Check the user guide below for more information https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/utilities.html